# Laravel 7 - Temporary Users

Tags: php, laravel, authentication, temporary, active-users

I'm kind of new in Laravel, so I want to know if someone can tell me the best way to implement a temporary user. I tried to add a variable that bring me the value of active and then try to added on the condition for each role, but it didn't work. Somebody can help me?

- I have this in my LoginController

```
    public function login()
        {
            $credentials = $this->validate(request(), [
                'email' => 'email|required|string',
                'password' => 'required|string',
            ]);
    
    
            if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) { //auth attemptdevuelve verdadero o falso en caso de que las credenciales correspondan o no
                //Inician cambios RDAN
                $user = Auth::user();
                if ($user->hasRole('admin')) {
                    return redirect('main');
                } else if ($user->hasRole('externo')) {
                    return redirect('es/user_form');
                } else if ($user->hasRole('profesor')) {
                    return redirect('main');
                } else if ($user->hasRole('registrador')) {
                    return redirect('select_lang');
                } else {
                    return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'Incorrect user permissions'])
                        ->withInput(request(['email']));
                }
                //Terminan cambios RDAN
    
            } else {
                return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'Incorrect user permissions'])
                    ->withInput(request(['email']));
            }
        }
```

In MySQL database I added an 'active' column of type 'tinyint(1)' in the table 'users'. So I want to add a condition or something that validates if the user is active(1) or inactive(0). Also I would like to add it in the view where the user 'admin' can enable or disable a user with a checkbox.

- Index view:

```
   <td class="small  text-center">
      <div class="row">
         <div>
           <!--VIEW-->
           <button onclick="verUsuario({{$user->id}})" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-success m-1">
           <i class="bi bi-eye align-content-center"></i>
           </button>
         </div>    
         <div>
           <!--EDIT-->
           <button onclick="editarUsuario({{$user->id}})" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning m-1">
           <i class="bi bi-pencil-fill align-content-center"></i>
           </button>
         </div>
           <!--Delete-->
           <form id="delete"  action="{{url('Usuario/'.$user->id)}}" method="post">
            {{csrf_field()}}
            {{method_field('DELETE')}}
              <button type="submit" onclick="return confirm('Va a borrar la usuario {{$user->name}} ¿está seguro?')" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-danger m-1">
              <i class="bi bi-trash-fill align-content-center"></i></button>
           </form>
        </div>
     </td>
```

Comment: And where is your problem exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add 1 more condition.

```
public function login()
        {
            $credentials = $this->validate(request(), [
                'email' => 'email|required|string',
                'password' => 'required|string',
            ]);
    

        if (Auth::attempt($credentials)) { //auth attemptdevuelve verdadero o falso en caso de que las credenciales correspondan o no
            //Inician cambios RDAN
            $user = Auth::user();
          if($user->active)  // checking your user is active or not
        {
            if ($user->hasRole('admin')) {
                return redirect('main');
            } else if ($user->hasRole('externo')) {
                return redirect('es/user_form');
            } else if ($user->hasRole('profesor')) {
                return redirect('main');
            } else if ($user->hasRole('registrador')) {
                return redirect('select_lang');
            } else {
                return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'Incorrect user permissions'])
                    ->withInput(request(['email']));
            }
          }
           else
          {
              Auth::logout(); //to logout user
        return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'Account Deactivated please contact admin'])->withInput(request(['email'])); // error message if user deactivated.
              }
            //Terminan cambios RDAN

        } else {
            return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'Incorrect user permissions'])
                ->withInput(request(['email']));
        }
    }
```

Coming to second part of your question you can simple call an ajax when checkbox checked or un-checked.

Comment: It still lets me log in despite having the 'active' value at 0. What could be the problem?

Comment: dd($user) and check $user->active value.

Comment: Yes, it appears in 0

Comment: check if its coming in this else
          {
        return back()->withErrors(['email' => 'Account Deactivated please contact admin'])->withInput(request(['email'])); // error message if user deactivated.
              }

Comment: Yes, it's there too.

Comment: i have updated my answer so when active = 0 it will redirect you back.